# Windows cannot determine which language to install?

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008, language, vmware-workstation

I want to install Windows Server 2008 SP2 on VMware Workstation 7.0.1 build-227600.

However during installation I receive the following error and Windows doesn't continue the installation procedure:

> Windows cannot determine which language to install?

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you are trying to do an upgrade with the upgrade disk having a different language than the original installation. It sounds like you have a fresh install, so this most likely isn't your problem. If this is the case, you probably just have a bad disk. Check the MD5 or just redownload.

Comment: Oh no, It was 1.9 GB to download. I don't wanna download it again :(

Comment: BTW, how can I get MD5 code of a file in Win 7 x64?

Comment: I checked the MD5, I've downloaded file correctly. I tried to install Win Server 2008 again, this time I didn't receive the error, so my problem has been solved.

Comment: Getting MD5 & SHA1 Hash code of a file in Win 7 => http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/77854-getting-md5-sha1-hash-code-file-win-7-a.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the bootable flash drive left in the server. Also, flash drive can cause windows 7 to throw errors when selecting installation partition.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the easy install option, use the option to install a blank VM. Then the installation will work normally.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer necessarily, but some observations that might help others.  Newer VMWare Workstation versions, at least version 16.0 and up, can create a VM from the current MSFT Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 ISO (en_windows_server_2008_r2_with_sp1_x64_dvd_617601.iso) using the easy install method.  So, you don't have to create a blank VM and install the OS later.

However, this is still an issue.  If you try to create a VM using an autounattend.xml file, like say with Hashicorp's Packer tool, you will run into the same issue reported here.  I have tried everything I can think of to fix the issue and no luck.  I even compared my .vmx that was generated via script versus that generated by VMWare Workstation and they are virtually identical.  My same script setup works with virtually every other MSFT OS ISO available, including Windows Server 2008 R2 (no SP1).  Because the error happens before the disk is even setup, there is no Windows install logging or Panther location to analyze to see what happened.  I would love to know what VMWare figured out to get around this issue.  I verified the hash on the ISO mentioned and it matches what Microsoft said it should be, so that is not the problem.  It is a fresh install as well, so it isn't a mismatch in languages during an upgrade either, which has been reported as a cause of this error.  If anyone figures out what really causes this issue, it sure would be helpful to those trying to script the creation of OS images versus manually creating VMs.  I suspect the ISO has an issue, but no way to prove.

Comment: AHA!!  I figured out the problem.  For this very specific version of Windows: Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, you CANNOT specify a product key in the autounattend.xml file.  If you do, you get the error reported for this thread, that is, the install fails with an Install error pop-up with message "Windows cannot determine which language to install."  This happens if there is a product key specified under 'UserData' in the 'Microsoft-Windows-Setup' component in the 'windowsPE' pass, and/or if there is a product key specified in the 'Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup' component in the 'specialize' pass.